# g++ Undefined Symbol Error using shared library

Tags: c++, linux, g++

The symbol is in the file. I verified it using nm & grep but I still get the undefined symbol error when I run the compiled application. Other symbols in the shared library are working just fine. The header file declares it as extern and it is not in a conditional pre-processor block. I'm new to c/c++ so any experience with something like this would be appreciated.

There are a ton of related questions on StackOverflow, but everyone is listing source files and headers that don't mean anything to the actual context of the question. This is a general programming question: Why can't g++ link the symbol into my compiled application? Header definition checks ok, the symbol is in the shared library, and other symbols are working properly.

Comment: Without an example it's hard to help you. Are you using the -lLIB_NAME argument when invoking g++?

Comment: Please add the relevant output lines from `nm` to your question.

Comment: If the symbol is not found at _runtime_ then it is nothing to do with g++. Use `ldd` to find out which shared library the application is actually trying to link against when it runs. Is it the location you expect?

Comment: @Troubadour ldd! Cool! Yup its linking to the system version not the develpment version which does not have the symbol. I'm using eclipse and I told it to use the local/lib path in build settings. I don't understand. here is the command fromthe auto generated makefile.
`g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "smash"  ./src/smash.o ./src/smash_init.o   -lnspr4 -lmozjs185` Why is it still picking up the lib in /usr/lib?

Comment: Is it a C or a C++ library? Did you check with `nm -C` that the library contains the mangled C++ symbol?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Its C++. As Troubadour has helped me discover, there is a different version of the library on my system that is getting loaded at runtime.

Comment: Note that for shared libraries, you almost always want `nm -D` when it comes to program linkage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to include the path to your development version of the library. This will ensure the run time linker (ld.so) will find it when you run your application.

Your build settings are fine but they don't affect what happens at run time. There are ways to "bake" paths into the executable at build time if you really want to. See the man page for ld.so to see how it searches for libraries.

Comment: It depends on what you are ultimately trying to do. If you will be replacing the library in /usr/lib then you only need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH temporarily during development. If you want to keep the /usr/lib version and always have your application use the /usr/local/lib version then you might want to consider starting your app via a script so that you can automatically set LD_LIBRARY_PATH (and anything else it might need).

Comment: I came up with a solution for my project. What I've done is completely rebranded the library that will ship with the application. This was easy due to the fact that the target library name was conveniently defined in the make file. See: [My MDN Wiki Entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation/Rebranding_SpiderMonkey_%281.8.5%29) for more information

Comment: Thanks for helping me track down the issue!

Comment: Replacing /usr/lib or relying on /usr/local/lib stands the chance of breaking other applications. I won't have my app being rude as guest on the host system.

Comment: All the same, I'm sure its a general enough Q&A to help some other poor souls who might be experiencing a similar issue.